# Merging common JSON objects

Tags: java, json

I'm looking for some assistance with taking an input JSON object, and merging the common items in that object in to an output that then groups the items from the input together, here is the problem given below:

Write code that converts the input JSON data to the output JSON format. It should be able to handle any number of levels of nesting. Each child can only have one parent (of type ‘folder’), and each parent may have multiple children (of type ‘folder’ or ‘file’).

Sample Input Data:

```
[
{
       name:'file1',
       parent:'folder1',
       type:'file'
},
{
       name:'file2',
       parent:'folder2',
       type:'file'
},
{
       name:'folder1',
       parent:'root',
       type:'folder'
},
{
       name:'folder2',
       parent:'folder1',
       type:'folder'
}
]
```

Sample Output Data:

```
[
       {
              name:'folder1',
              parent:'root',
              type:'folder',
              children:[
                     {
                           name:'file1',
                           parent:'folder1',
                           type:'file'
                     },
                     {
                           name:'folder2',
                           parent:'folder1',
                           type:'folder',
                           children:[
                                  {
                                         name:'file2',
                                         parent:'folder2',
                                         type:'file'
                                  }
                           ]
                     }
              ]
       }
]
```

Comment: What, _specifically_, do you need help with?

Comment: Unless you can provide an explanation of a specific problem, everyone is inclined to believe that this is homework.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for how to merge the groups together for the output based on the common parameters of the input, I'm not really sure what more specifics to provide.

Comment: I know what I need to do is take in the input json, and then create a folder structure, starting from root - and then start recursively listing folders based on the parent relationship each represents - I'm just trying to work out the beginnings of getting the json object from a file and then looping through and parting the objects out - from there is where I am going to have some more confusion for creating the output structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The problem has parts: reading the JSON into memory, processing the in-memory representation, and outputting the results.
2. A simple reading of the required output tells you that the data structure is different.  You have extra attributes ...
3. Presumably you have been given some instruction on techniques for reading / writing JSON ... or links / references to documentation.
4. Recursion is not necessary.  Basically you need a temporary data structure that "maps" a name to an object, and you use that to help you connect the parts of the tree together.  (Think about it!  There is a Java interface called `Map` ...)

---

Basically, you need to work through this yourself.  That's how you learn.  The confusion you are experience is typical for beginners ... but the more practice you get, the easier it will be.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did post this as kind of a beginner type of question around how to do some intermediate level json parsing. I will take these tips as a great answer!

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for was help with breaking down the individual parts of the problem, rather than the specific code itself. Knowing that I have to do some mapping of a given structure to assume the output structure and adding some logic outside of that to allow for nesting is a great gain - thank you!